# login via facebook using asp.net

Tags: c#

I just want to integrate facebook in my web site. When I logged-in facebook want to logged -in  my web site as well .but I am facing some problem.
When I am using this code for log-in with my email id in facebook. its work fine and i get all details . but when I log-in with a different user id of facebook then it shows following error.

```
Error
App Not Setup: The developers of this app have not set up this app properly for Facebook Login.
```

please solve this problem.
thank you

Comment: your problem solve or not..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to go http://developer.facebook.com/ and  click on setting Advance setting or set the public.

Comment: if u show me the code the it better helpful for me.

Comment: you have to go developer.facebook.com after that go to status and review menu and check yes.